# ID dinamico en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hola tengo este siguiente switch:

[image: switch]

Lo cual es generado dinamicamente y esta compuesto por le siguiente código:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in modelo_final">
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:100px;">
      <div class="can-toggle demo-rebrand-2">
          <input id=IDDINAMICO type="checkbox" ng-model="modeloCustom[modulo.id]">
          <label for=IDDINAMICO>
              <div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="Yes" data-unchecked="No"></div>
              <div class="can-toggle__label-text">
                  <p style="font-size:15px; width:100px;">{{model.nombre}}</p>
              </div>
          </label>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Y resulta que el *input* del switch depende de un *label* para funcionar, la cual están relacionados con un ID y este necesito que sea dinamico para que puedan usarse independientemente y no que uno mueva a todos...

Probe con `id={{$index}}` y `for={{$index}}` y aún se siguen moviendo todos juntos... como lo soluciono?

saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado utilizar el objeto/array que viene desde el ng-repeat? por ejemplo `<input id={{model.id}}>`?

Comment: si, el problema era el ng-model